# Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I delete an array's element using the element's name, so without knowing its index:

```
arr = ["hello", "apple", "orange"]
arr.delete("hello") /*method which delete the element by giving the element's name*/
```

And I want to get:

```
arr = ["apple", "orange"]
```

It's good for me even to delete the element using his index, but I have to get the index using the element's name, because I can't know It How can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "exact bane if the element"?

Comment: `name` of the element you say...  can you be more specific?

Comment: @FlavioManna please define what you mean by `name`

Comment: if you mean `by value` then look at the answer given.  If you want to identify the element by a `name` property, that is a different situation.  @FlavioManna

Comment: @FlavioManna  ok, then the provided answer is what you want.  `arr.splice(arr.indexOf('h'), 1);` in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array like this:

```
var arr = [
  'one',
  'two',
  'three'
];
```

You can remove the item with the value 'two' like this:

```
arr.splice(arr.indexOf('two'), 1);
```

[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns the index of the value 'two' in the array.

[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) removes items from the array using the index. In this case we remove 1 item at the index returned by indexOf.

Comment: This will only remove the first instance if there are repeated values `["a", "b", "b", "c"]` for example then the result would be `["a", "b", "c"]`.

Comment: @Pat Leahy so if I have var arr = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"] and I do arr.splice(arr.indexOf("h"), 1) I should get: arr = ["e", "l", "l", "o"] right?

Comment: @FlavioManna Yes, but as VLAZ points out if you have var arr = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"] and I do arr.splice(arr.indexOf("l"), 1) you will get ["h", "e", "l", "o"]. Only the first "l" will be removed.